# Custom string padding

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column that is in an incorrect format. For example, my data in row one has the id "1" but it needs to be of the form: `tt0000001` and id "23212" would need to be: `tt0023212`

Is there a way I can transform all my data for a column into this format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("tt%07d", 1)
sprintf("tt%07d", 23212)
```

EDIT

Yes, you can do this for each column:

```
vec <- seq(37, 2000, 100)
sprintf("tt%07d", vec)
[1] "tt0000037" "tt0000137" "tt0000237" "tt0000337"
[5] "tt0000437" "tt0000537" "tt0000637" "tt0000737"
[9] "tt0000837" "tt0000937" "tt0001037" "tt0001137"
[13] "tt0001237" "tt0001337" "tt0001437" "tt0001537"
[17] "tt0001637" "tt0001737" "tt0001837" "tt0001937"
```

Consider that `vec` is your id column (eg. `df$id`).

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can do this for all the rows in the data frame? I have 21m of them so don't want to do it manually for each :)

Comment: Thanks! I did just and it works. However, it prints the outcome instead of updating my data frame. Is there a way to update the data frame?

Comment: Just assign the new values to it: `df$id <- sprintf("tt%07d", df$id)`

Answer (score 1):

Using stringr package:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(id = c("1","23212"))

library(stringr)
df$id1 <- paste0("tt", str_pad(myNames, 7, "left", "0"))

#result
df

#      id       id1
# 1     1 tt0000001
# 2 23212 tt0023212
```